# Sonatype Nexus: User managed Custom Admin Roles are not able to view logs & gets an error while viewing Capabilities (in Nexus UI)

Tags: nexus, privileges, role, sonatype

I have a Admin user with restricted access to repositories. That is, I create a user and gave  access to everything except create/delete access to repositories. But this shouldn't stop the user from viewing logs and capabilities section in Nexus.

I've 2 issues for this user, (1) the user is not able to view the contents of "Log" tab in Nexus UI and (2) the user gets a 403 error message popup box while the user tries to view the "capabilities" Section in Nexus UI. Please see the below details.

1) I see the below warning in nexus.log file when the user tries to view the Log tab in Nexus:

```
2014-02-20 10:31:58 WARN  [qtp11244797-36] testadmin org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.siesta.AuthorizationExceptionMapper - (ID 085cefa0-58da-45c7-97cc-ca6e1365e8ff) Response: [403] (no entity/body) mapped from org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException/User is not permitted: nexus:log:read
```

Below is the screenshot when the user tries to see logs in Nexus UI.

[image]

2) The 403 forbidden error message popup box is slightly different from the above Log issue. Thing is, the user is able to view/change all capabilities just by simply hitting the "ok" button.

I see the below warning in nexus.log file when the user tries to view the capabilities tab in Nexus UI:

```
2014-02-20 11:26:05 WARN  [qtp11244797-36] testadmin org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.siesta.AuthorizationExceptionMapper - (ID 1b04266c-b14b-44c7-a145-7db119cd492e) Response: [403] ErrorXO{id='1b04266c-b14b-44c7-a145-7db119cd492e', message='User is not permitted: nexus:capabilityTypesread'} mapped from org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException/User is not permitted: nexus:capabilityTypesread
```

Below is the screenshot when the user tries to see capabilities in Nexus UI.

[image]

Below is the Screenshot of the Role & Privileges of this admin user:

[image]

Please let me know if I'm missing anything here and thanks for the help in advance.!!!!!

-Dinesh

Comment: Can somebody look into this, please?

Comment: wow! no body seen this before?